# Python k-mean, centroids are placed outside of the clusters

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to perform clustering of mixed data with k-means algorithm: `chemical_1`, `chemical_2` - numerical, `season` - categorical.
A `season` column was transformed to dummies in order to use it in K-means algorithm.

I've added the cluster centers with `plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], marker="x", color='r')` but it placed them into the wrong position, outside the clusters.
How should I handle `kmeans.cluster_centers_` to be able to plot them correctly?

[image]

```
#Make a copy of DF
df_transformed = df

#Transform the 'season' to dummies
df_transformed = pd.get_dummies(df_transformed, columns=['season'])

#Standardize
columns = ['chemical_1', 'chemical_2', 'season_winter', 'season_spring', 'season_autumn', 'season_summer']
df_tr_std = stats.zscore(df_transformed[columns])

#Cluster the data
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4).fit(df_tr_std)
labels = kmeans.labels_
centers = np.array(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

#Glue back to original data
df_transformed['clusters'] = labels

#Add the column into our list
columns.extend(['clusters'])

#Analyzing the clusters
print(df_transformed[columns].groupby(['clusters']).mean())

          chemical_1  chemical_2  season_winter  season_spring  season_autumn  \
clusters                                                                        
0           7.951500   10.600500              0              0              1   
1           8.119180    8.818852              1              0              0   
2           8.024423    8.009615              0              1              0   
3           7.939432    9.414773              0              0              0   

          season_summer  
clusters                 
0                     0  
1                     0  
2                     0  
3                     1

#Scatter plot of chemical_1 and chemical_2
sns.lmplot('chemical_1', 'chemical_2', 
           data=df_transformed,
           size = 10,
           fit_reg=False, 
           hue="clusters",  
           scatter_kws={"marker": "D", 
                        "s": 100}
          )
plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], marker="x", color='r')

plt.title('Clusters chemical_1 vs chemical_2')
plt.xlabel('chemical_1')
plt.ylabel('chemical_2')
plt.show
```

**UPD:** I tried to use PCA for transformation. Is it the right way? Also, I could plot the data only with matplotlib. What is the proper way to use seaborn here?

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2, whiten=True).fit(df_tr_std)

#Cluster the data
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(df_tr_std)
labels = kmeans.labels_
centers = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

plt.scatter(df_tr_std[:,0], df_tr_std[:,1])
plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], marker="x", color='r')
```

Now the scatter plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The line below `#Make a copy of DF` ... does precisely the opposite of making a copy. You should use `copy` explicitly.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have multi-dimensional data, but you're plotting the first two columns only. That is completely incorrect. You'd need to first find their projections in 2D space before plotting them.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I probably have to transform back after doing `df_tr_std = stats.zscore(df_transformed[columns])` in order to plot centroids in the correct coordinates. But I'm stuck at this step

Comment: So, let me make sure I've understood... you've taken the 'season' label and lumped it in with your features? Why would you do that?

Comment: Also, where does your data come from?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my data comes from [Coil 1999 Competition Data Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Coil+1999+Competition+Data). I've transformed seasons to dummies because k-means can not work with categorical features. But I don't know what is the correct way to map z-scores back to the old coordinate system as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you cluster the z-scores, the resulting centers will be zscores, too.

Kmeans obviously cannot map them back to your old coordinate system - you have to do that yourself.

Since the z score transformation is a simple *linear* transformation, it is straightforward to recreate this function *and* the inverse transformation.

Comment: I've read scipy documentation on z score and investigated how to map z-scores back to the old coordinate system. But still haven't found a relevant solution and now just stuck with this problem. I don't have much experience in python and statistics yet and at this point need help. Could you please show an example in code how to perform the transformation in my case?

Comment: The transform is just (x-mu)/sigma. The inverse is trivial to figure out.

Comment: I think I'm not smart enough, sorry. It is not trivial for me. I don't know what transformation and where should I apply. After researching the problem I came up with the following solution and updated my post accordingly: `centers = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)`. But not sure if it is correct.

Comment: No, PCA is not the inverse of zscore.

Comment: You really need to do the math. The inverse of x_zscore=(x-mu)/sigma obviously is x=x_zscore*sigma+mu... Yes, very very basic calculus...