# K-Means algorithm Centroids are not placed in the clusters

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means, centroid

I have a problem. I want to cluster my dataset. Unfortunately my centroids are not in the clusters but outside. I have already read
[Python k-mean, centroids are placed outside of the clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124484/python-k-mean-centroids-are-placed-outside-of-the-clusters) about this.

However, I do not know what could be the reason. How can I cluster correctly?

You can find the dataset at https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Coderanker3/24c948d2ff0b7f71e51b3774c2cc7b22/raw/253ba0660720de3a9cf7dee2a2d25a37f61095ca/Dataset

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Coderanker3/24c948d2ff0b7f71e51b3774c2cc7b22/raw/253ba0660720de3a9cf7dee2a2d25a37f61095ca/Dataset')
df.shape

features_clustering = ['review_scores_accuracy',
 'distance_to_center',
 'bedrooms',
 'review_scores_location',
 'review_scores_value',
 'number_of_reviews',
 'beds',
 'review_scores_communication',
 'accommodates',
 'review_scores_checkin',
 'amenities_count',
 'review_scores_rating',
 'reviews_per_month',
 'corrected_price']

df_cluster = df[features_clustering].copy()
X = df_cluster.copy()

model = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=53, n_init=10, max_iter=1000, tol=0.0001)
clusters = model.fit_predict(X)
df_cluster["cluster"] = clusters

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
sns.scatterplot(data=df_cluster, x="amenities_count", y="corrected_price", hue="cluster", palette='Set2_r')
sns.scatterplot(x=model.cluster_centers_[:,0], y=model.cluster_centers_[:,1], color='blue',marker='*',
                            label='centroid', s=250)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
#plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.xlim(xmin=-0.1)
plt.show()

model.cluster_centers_
```

[image]

```py
inertia = model.inertia_
sil = metrics.silhouette_score(X,model.labels_)

print(f'inertia {inertia:.3f}')
print(f'silhouette {sil:.3f}')

[OUT]

inertia 4490.076
silhouette 0.156
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your main question: the cluster centers are *not* outside of your clusters.

1 : You are clustering over **14** features shown in `features_clustering` list.

2 : You are viewing the clusters over a two-dimensional space, arbitrarily choosing `amenities_count` and `corrected_price` for the data and two coordinates for the cluster centers `x=model.cluster_centers_[:,0], y=model.cluster_centers_[:,1]` which don't correspond to the same features.

For these reasons you are going to get strange results; they really don't mean anything.

The bottom line is you cannot view 14 dimension clustering over two-dimensions.

To show point 2 more clearly, change the plotting of the clusters line to

```py
sns.scatterplot(x=model.cluster_centers_[:,10], y=model.cluster_centers_[:,13], color='blue',marker='*', label='centroid', s=250)
```

to be plotting the cluster centers against the same features as the data.

---

The link to the SO answer about the cluster centers being outside of the cluster data is about scaling the data before clustering to be between 0 and 1, and then not scaling the cluster centers back up when plotting with the real data. This is not the same as your issues here.

Answer (score 1):

You are making multidimensional clusters and you want them to fit a two-dimensional map, by itself it will not work. Let me explain, a variable is a dimension: x1,x2,x3,...,xn and if you find the clusters it will give you as a result y1,y2,y3,...,yn. If you map in 2D the result as you are doing, (I take your example)
x1  is "amenities_count", x5 is "corrected_price".

It will create a 2D map of only these two variables and surely the plotter, seeing that you use a 2D map, will only take the first two variables from cluster, y1 and y2 to plot. Note that xi has no direct relationship with y1.

You must: 1) do a conversion to find its corresponding x,y or 2) reduce the dimensionality of the data you are using to generate a 2D map with the information of all the variables.

For the first case, I am not very sure because I have never done it (Remapping the data).
But in the dimensionality reduction, I recommend you to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding or the classic PCA.

Moral: if you want to see a 2D cluster, make sure you only have 2 variables.